# PHPMailer Call to a member function isSMTP() on null

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

I'm trying to update my Wordpress plugin since the location of PHPMailer is moved in wordpress 5.5.

I'm testing in Wordpress version 5.1 right now and i'm encountering the following error

`Fatal error: Call to a member function isSMTP() on null in (path) on line (line)`

As shown in the code below i've tried var_dumping the class methods and it shows `isSMTP` but when i call it a line later it returns the error.

```
      if (!class_exists("\\PHPMailer")) {
        global $wp_version;
        if ( version_compare( $wp_version, '5.5', '<' ) ) {
          require_once(\ABSPATH . \WPINC . "/class-phpmailer.php");
          require_once(\ABSPATH . \WPINC . "/class-smtp.php");
          require_once(\ABSPATH . \WPINC . "/class-pop3.php");
          $oPhpMailer = new \PHPMailer();
        }else {
          require_once(\ABSPATH . \WPINC . "/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php");
          require_once(\ABSPATH . \WPINC . "/PHPMailer/SMTP.php");
          require_once(\ABSPATH . \WPINC . "/class-pop3.php");
          $oPhpMailer = new PHPMailer();
        }
      }

      var_dump(get_class_methods($oPhpMailer));
      $oPhpMailer->isSMTP();
```

Comment: Wordpress bundles PHPMailer, and will load it for you. You should not need to load PHPMailer yourself at all. Look at [`wp_mail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) and the associated [`phpmailer_init`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/phpmailer_init/) hook that allows you to get hold of the PHPMailer instance and do what you like with it. This approach is also likely to survive Wordpress upgrades in a way that your approach will not.

Comment: Your'e also missing a `use` statement in the code you posted, so the `PHPMailer` class will not be found correctly in WP 5.5 because it's missing a FQCN.

Comment: Good point @Synchro i will check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `if (!class_exists("\\PHPMailer"))` returns false (which means the class exists). You don't set `$oPhpMailer` in this case which means `$oPhpMailer = null`. That is what the error means: you cannot run `null->isSMTP()`.

It could very well be that this code is ran twice - the first time the `$oPhpMailer` gets set because the class does not exists (which is why you get the `get_class_methods` output). The second time the class exists, so the variable is null.

Try adding an else

```
if (!class_exists("\\PHPMailer")) {
  // ...
} else {
  $oPhpMailer = new \PHPMailer();
}
```

Comment: Not sure how `var_dump(get_class_methods($oPhpMailer));` would have worked then though, OP is saying that actually listed methods – but if `$oPhpMailer` was null, that should not have been possible to begin with.

Comment: @04FS Added extra explaination - the code is probably ran twice, first where the class does not exiusts (hence vardump output) and the second time it does.

Comment: This seemed to be the case. indeed the code was ran twice. Thank you so much!!